Mapping features and labels for ML when they don't reside in a dataframe
How to correctly import images for a neural network model with its labels?
Hi, I am trying to create an image recognition neural network (either a DNN or use a trained CNN on which I may add more layers to suit my classes). I have previously worked on data that resides in a dataframe format, where multiple columns are features and their corresponding column is the target label. But now I am working on images where the features are the image data and the target label is the name of the respective folder in which the images reside. So in this case, how do I make sure the images get mapped to the correct label?
The images I have are of 5 classes. They reside in separate folders, each for one class. And most importantly the class names are the same as folder names. So, images of class XYZ are all in a folder called XYZ, images of class ABC are all in a folder called ABC. There are 5 such folders. And all these 5 folders are in a parent folder called, say, ParentFolder. The names of the image files itself are all random names that don't mean anything.
This is how I'm importing the data:
Path to the extracted dataset
data_dir = 'here I have written the local path'
Verify paths and dataset structure
folders = os.listdir(data_dir)
print("Folders:", folders)
Step 3: Load and prepare the dataset
data = load_files(data_dir)
X = np.array(data['filenames'])
y = np.array(data['target'])

My question is this: how do I know that once I import the data with above code, the labels get matched correctly with the features, ie all data of images residing in folder XYZ will become features of target label of XYZ?
Do I have to code this info somewhere?
BTW, I have been able to further process the images, make arrays and feed it into a model and its giving me results. But how do I know the model has mapped the features and label data correctly?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
